# Insert multiple values from text box to the data base using the list<string>

Tags: asp.net, sql

1. This is the required image, I want to insert multiple value through Name, Employee Code and E-mail Id, by submit button which is in this page.
2. My database contains following field Id(primary key),Name (varchar 50),Employee Code (varchar 50), E-mail Id (varchar 50).
3. In the data layer, I code as following:

   ```
   public static bool AddParticipantlistemployeecode(DimensionQuestion dimension)
      {
          bool result;


          using (var helper = new DbHelper())
          {
              _cmdtext = "sp_NewGeneratedUniqueCode";

              var success = new SqlParameter("@Success", SqlDbType.Bit, 1,    ParameterDirection.Output, true, 0, 0,
                                             "Result", DataRowVersion.Default, 0);

              foreach (string s in dimension.CandidateName)
              {
                  if (s.Trim().Length > 0)
                  {
                      var parameter = new[]
                                   {
                                      // new   SqlParameter("@CompanyName",dimension.CompanyName  ),
                                       new SqlParameter("@CandidateName",s  ),
                                       new SqlParameter("@EmployeeCode",s  ),
                                       new SqlParameter("@EmailId",s  ),                                                                             
                                       success,
                                   };
                      helper.ExecuteScalar(_cmdtext, CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameter);
                  }
              }

              result = (bool)success.Value;
          }


          return result;
      }
   ```
4. In the Model layer:

   ```
   using System.Text;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   namespace Cengrow.Survey.Core.Model
   {
   public class DimensionQuestion
   {
       public string CompanyName { get; set; }
      // public string DimensionNumber { get; set; }
       public List<string> CandidateName { get; set; }
       public List<string> EmployeeCode { get; set; }
       public List<string> EmailId { get; set; }
       public int DimensionName { get; set; }
       public string Section { get; set; }
       //public string Rating { get; set; }
       public List<string> Questions { get; set; }
       //public string Question2 { get; set; }
       //public string Question3 { get; set; }
       //public string Question4 { get; set; }
       //public string Question5 { get; set; }
       //public string Question6 { get; set; }
       //public string Question7 { get; set; }
       //public string Question8 { get; set; }
       //public string Question9 { get; set; }
       //public string Question10 { get; set; }
       //public string Question11 { get; set; }
       //public string Question12 { get; set; }
       //public string Question13 { get; set; }
       //public string Question14 { get; set; }
       //public string Question15 { get; set; }

   }
   }
   ```
5. And finally in the business logic on the button click:

   ```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           try
           {
               FillObjects();

               //if (InsertData.InsertCandidateCompany(_CandidateCompanyInformation )) 
               if (InsertData.AddParticipantlistemployeecode(_DimensionQuestion))
               {
                   ShowMessage("Information is saved");
                   //Reset();

               }
               else
               {
                   ShowMessage("Please try again");

               }
           }
           finally
           {
               _DimensionQuestion = null;

           }
       }

    private void FillObjects()
       {
           List<string> sp = new List<string>();
           _DimensionQuestion = new Cengrow.Survey.Core.Model.DimensionQuestion();
          // _DimensionQuestion.CompanyName = txtCompanyName.Text.Trim();


           sp.Add(txtName1.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName2.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName3.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName4.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName5.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName6.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName7.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName8.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName9.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName10.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName11.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName12.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName13.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName14.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName15.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName16.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName17.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName18.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName19.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName20.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName21.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName22.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName23.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName24.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtName25.Text.Trim());
           _DimensionQuestion.CandidateName = sp;

           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode1.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode2.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode3.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode4.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode5.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode6.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode7.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode8.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode9.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode10.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode11.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode12.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode13.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode14.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode15.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode16.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode17.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode18.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode19.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode20.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode21.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode22.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode23.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode24.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(txtEmployeeCode25.Text.Trim());
           _DimensionQuestion.EmployeeCode = sp;

           sp.Add(TextBox1.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox2.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox3.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox4.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox5.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox6.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox7.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox8.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox9.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox10.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox11.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox12.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox13.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox14.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox15.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox16.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox17.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox18.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox19.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox20.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox21.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox22.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox23.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox24.Text.Trim());
           sp.Add(TextBox25.Text.Trim());
           _DimensionQuestion.EmailId  = sp;
        }
   ```

**The data is not coming proper into the database**

Comment: What do you mean by "not coming proper"?

Comment: means in the data base Name ,EmployeeCode,Emailid is updated 3 times if we insert in any one row inside the text box

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same value to all three parameters:

```
new SqlParameter("@CandidateName",s  ),
new SqlParameter("@EmployeeCode",s  ),
new SqlParameter("@EmailId",s
```

In all cases you are adding "s" which is CandidateName.

Edit: Candidate should be a class:

```
public class Candidate
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public Candidate(string name, string code, string email)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.EmployeeCode = code;
        this.Email = email;
    }
}
```

Then your DimensionQuestion should contain a

```
List<Candidate> Candidates
```

instead of

```
public List<string> CandidateName { get; set; }
public List<string> EmployeeCode { get; set; }
public List<string> EmailId { get; set; }
```

Then you FillObjects method add Candidate objects to the Candidates list

```
Candidates.Add(new Candidate(txtName1.Text.Trim(), 
                                txtEmployeeCode1.Text.Trim(), 
                                TextBox1.Text.Trim()));


Candidates.Add(new Candidate(txtName2.Text.Trim(), 
                                txtEmployeeCode2.Text.Trim(), 
                                TextBox2.Text.Trim()));
```

Finaly your data layer should be:

```
foreach (Candidate candidate in dimension.Candidates)
           {
               if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(candidate.Name))
               {
                   var parameter = new[]
                                {
                                   // new   SqlParameter("@CompanyName",dimension.CompanyName  ),
                                    new SqlParameter("@CandidateName",candidate.Name  ),
                                    new SqlParameter("@EmployeeCode",candidate.Code  ),
                                    new SqlParameter("@EmailId",candidate.Email  ),                                                                             
                                    success,
                                };
                   helper.ExecuteScalar(_cmdtext, CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameter);
               }
           }
```